# Stop execution of cmdlet in ProcessRecord

Tags: c#, powershell

How does one stop the execution of a cmdlet that takes in pipeline input in the ProcessRecord method. If a condition in ProcessRecord is not met, I need to immediately stop execution and return a `false`:

```
protected override void BeginProcessing()
{
    _output = true;
}

protected override void ProcessRecord()
{
    //processing
    if(condtion == true) return;

    _output = false;
    //How do I stop processing now, and ensure _output is returned as result?
}

protected override void EndProcessing()
{
    WriteObject(_output);
}
```

`PipelineStoppedException` seems to work, but doesn't give me the exact behaviour.

Updated with a more concrete example, using `PipelineStoppedException`:

Let's consider a cmdlet `First-List` which is supposed to behave similar to `First()` in LINQ. An implementation of this cmdlet would be like:

```
[Cmdlet("First", "List")]
public class FirstList : Cmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipeline = true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true)]
    public object Input { get; set; }

    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = true)]
    public ScriptBlock ScriptBlock { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        var output = ScriptBlock.InvokeWithContext(null, new List<PSVariable>
        {
            new PSVariable("input", Input),
        })[0];

        if (output.ToString() != "True") return;

        WriteObject(Input);
        throw new PipelineStoppedException();
    }

    protected override void EndProcessing()
    {
        Error.NoMatch();
    }
}
```

With `Select -First`, I am able to do the following:

```
$a = 1..10 | Select -First 1
#$a is 1
```

But with my implementtion:

```
$a = 1..10 | First-List { $input -ge 5 }
#$a should be assigned 5, but it is not
```

But `1..10 | First-List { $input -ge 5 }` does indeed output 5.

Update 2:

It seems like `Select-Object` actually throws `StopUpstreamCommandsException`.

There is also a feedback to have this available here - https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/768650/enable-users-to-stop-pipeline-making-stopupstreamcommandsexception-public

Comment: The PipelineStoppedException mentioned already is how you stop a whole pipeline.  It really does actually STOP things, though.

For instance, if you do:  ``dir | move -destination C:\otherfolder -passthru | select -first 10`` on PS4, Select-Object will throw PipelineStoppedException and only the first 10 files would be moved.

If that's what you're after, perfect. Otherwise, you need to explain what you mean by "stop execution" ;-)

Comment: @Jaykul - Thanks for that. Please check my updated question on more details and why `PipelineStoppedException` doesn't seem to be ideal for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the behaviour of `Select -First` by throwing the `StopUpstreamCommandsException`. But since it was internal to `System.Management.Automation`, had to use reflection. Wrote a utility method that looks like below:

```
internal static class Error
{
    private static readonly Type StopUpstreamCommandsExceptionType =
        Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (PSCmdlet))
            .GetType("System.Management.Automation.StopUpstreamCommandsException");

    internal static Exception StopUpstreamCommandsException(Cmdlet cmdlet)
    {
        var stopUpstreamCommandsException = (Exception) Activator.CreateInstance(StopUpstreamCommandsExceptionType,
            BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
            null,
            new Object[] {(InternalCommand) cmdlet},
            null
            );
        return stopUpstreamCommandsException;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not at my dev machine at the moment.  Does it work if you throw a `System.Management.Automation.PipelineStoppedException`?

Comment: Thanks for that. Please check my updated question on more details and why `PipelineStoppedException` doesn't seem to be ideal for me.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the built-in cmdlets throw a System.Management.Automation.PipelineStoppedException when they want to halt the running pipeline.  E.g., that's how select-object -first N works.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks for that. Please check my updated question on more details and why PipelineStoppedException doesn't seem to be ideal for me.